# Convert multiple SQL rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Afternoon good people of Stack Overflow.

I am trying to do something that I am not certain how to achieve with my SQL knowledge, but I have a clear idea what it is I want out of this so hopefully this will make sense to people.

I have some perfmon disk results that look like this:

```
DatabaseName    ObjectName      CounterName         InstanceName                Server      Average
DAG1DB01        logicaldisk     avg. disk sec/read  d:\mountpoints\DAG1DB01     Server1     13.616
DAG1DB01        logicaldisk     avg. disk sec/read  d:\mountpoints\DAG1DB01     Server2     17.508
DAG1DB01        logicaldisk     avg. disk sec/read  d:\mountpoints\DAG1DB01     Server3     12.775
DAG1DB01        logicaldisk     avg. disk sec/read  d:\mountpoints\DAG1DB01     Server4     13.148
DAG1DB01        logicaldisk     avg. disk sec/read  d:\mountpoints\DAG1DB01     Server5     10.091
```

These are example rows based on this query:

```
SELECT
e14_db.DatabaseName AS [DatabaseName],
d.ObjectName,
d.CounterName,
d.InstanceName,
d.Server,
AVG(Value) * 1000 AS [Average]
FROM E14_Perfmon_MBX AS d
INNER JOIN E14_Databases AS e14_db
ON e14_db.LogFolderPath = d.InstanceName
WHERE d.ObjectName = 'logicaldisk'
AND d.CounterName = 'avg. disk sec/read'
AND d.DateTime > (DATEADD(hh, -4, GETDATE()))
AND d.Value < 1
GROUP BY d.ObjectName, d.CounterName, d.InstanceName, d.Server, e14_db.DatabaseName
ORDER BY e14_db.DatabaseName, d.Server
```

What I want is this:

```
DatabaseName    ObjectName      CounterName         InstanceName                Server1     Server2     Server3     Server4     Server5
DAG1DB01        logicaldisk     avg. disk sec/read  d:\mountpoints\DAG1DB01     13.616      17.508      12.775      13.148      10.091
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? basically applying the rows onto themselves?

If any clarification is needed please feel free to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this on SO. Just do a search with sql-server and pivot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pivot with an indefinite amount of distinct values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803483/pivot-with-an-indefinite-amount-of-distinct-values)

Comment: @HungryHippos - What is missing in my post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement calculates separate averages for each server in a fixed number of columns (from 1 to 5):

```
SELECT e14_db.DatabaseName AS [DatabaseName]
, d.ObjectName, d.CounterName, d.InstanceName
, AVG(CASE WHEN d.Server = 'Server1' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) *1000 AS [Server1]
, AVG(CASE WHEN d.Server = 'Server2' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) *1000 AS [Server2]
, AVG(CASE WHEN d.Server = 'Server3' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) *1000 AS [Server3]
, AVG(CASE WHEN d.Server = 'Server4' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) *1000 AS [Server4]
, AVG(CASE WHEN d.Server = 'Server5' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) *1000 AS [Server5]
FROM E14_Perfmon_MBX AS d
INNER JOIN E14_Databases AS e14_db
ON e14_db.LogFolderPath = d.InstanceName
WHERE d.ObjectName = 'logicaldisk'
AND d.CounterName = 'avg. disk sec/read'
AND d.DateTime > (DATEADD(hh, -4, GETDATE()))
AND d.Value < 1
GROUP BY d.ObjectName, d.CounterName, d.InstanceName, e14_db.DatabaseName
ORDER BY e14_db.DatabaseName
```

You can use `PIVOT` as well, but this syntax is supported by a broader range of SQL *flavors*.

Comment: This one worked best for me and I understood it the best. Thanks to everyone for all of the suggestions though, I think PIVOT would also work if I could get my head around it properly, but this takes 0 seconds to execute so i'm happy with the performance I am getting!

Answer (score 1):

The [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.90%29.aspx) operator is designed for scenarios like this.  This should give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DatabaseName, 
    ObjectName, 
    CounterName, 
    InstanceName, 
    Server1, 
    Server2, 
    Server3, 
    Server4, 
    Server5 
FROM (SELECT
        e14_db.DatabaseName AS [DatabaseName],
        d.ObjectName,
        d.CounterName,
        d.InstanceName,
        d.[Server],
        d.Value * 1000 AS [Value]
    FROM E14_Perfmon_MBX AS d
        INNER JOIN E14_Databases AS e14_db
            ON e14_db.LogFolderPath = d.InstanceName
    WHERE d.ObjectName = 'logicaldisk'
        AND d.CounterName = 'avg. disk sec/read'
        AND d.DateTime > (DATEADD(hh, -4, GETDATE()))
        AND d.Value < 1) sub
PIVOT
(
    AVG(Value)
    FOR [Server] IN ([Server1], [Server2], [Server3], [Server4], [Server5])
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

[Click here to see DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc580/4)

```
declare @Servers varchar(1000) = ''
declare @Query varchar(8000) = ''


select @Servers = ISNULL(QuoteName(Server) + ',', '') + @Servers from MyTable

set @Servers = SUBSTRING(@Servers,0,len(@Servers))

Set @Query = 'Select DatabaseName, obectName, CounterName, InstanceName , ' + 
@Servers + ' From 
(
    Select DatabaseName, obectName, CounterName, InstanceName, 
    Server, Average from Mytable
)K Pivot
(
    max(Average) FOR Server IN (' + @Servers + ')
) AS pvt'

EXEC(@Query)
```

**Approach #2**

[Click here to see DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc580/3)

```
Select DatabaseName, obectName, CounterName, InstanceName , Server1, Server2, 
Server3, Server4, Server5
From 
(
    Select Select DatabaseName, obectName, CounterName, InstanceName, 
    Server, Average from Mytable FROM Mytable
)K
Pivot
(
    Max(Average) FOR Server IN (Server1, Server2, Server3, Server4, Server5)
) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining to the PERFMON table once for each server, something like this:

```
FROM E14_Databases AS e14_db
INNER JOIN E14_Perfmon_MBX AS server1
ON e14_db.LogFolderPath = server1.InstanceName 
AND server1.Server = 'Server1'
AND server1.ObjectName = 'logicaldisk'
AND server1.CounterName = 'avg. disk sec/read'
AND server1.DateTime > (DATEADD(hh, -4, GETDATE()))
AND server1.Value < 1
INNER JOIN E14_Perfmon_MBX AS server2
ON e14_db.LogFolderPath = server2.InstanceName 
AND server2.Server = 'Server2'
AND server2.ObjectName = 'logicaldisk'
AND server2.CounterName = 'avg. disk sec/read'
AND server2.DateTime > (DATEADD(hh, -4, GETDATE()))
AND server2.Value < 1
```

Then add one column for each join:

```
AVG(Server1.Value) * 1000 AS [Server1]
```

Comment: This works, although you should at minimum be using a CTE to do some of the basic initial restriction/aggregation, and only do the joins to get the individual columns.  However, as a number of other answers note, SQL Server has built-in functionality to do this for you.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the PIVOT table syntax as shown in this link here.

[Pivot table example](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx)

This will allow you to do what you are asking. Make sure to look at the section with generating the column headers dynamically.

Comment: Could you maybe summarize how this applies to the OPs case?  It's good you know to suggest this, but try to apply this in an example to the question.

Answer (score -3):

modify the table to include the extra columns, and run an update Where server = 'Server2'

update d set server2 = value of previous server entry (where server = 'server2' for example)

it is a pain to do it that way, but the only other option is to physically edit the table without using SQL statements.

Edit: what i recommend is making 2 tables, one with all the information on it (database name etc) and then one with the scores

Comment: -1 - This is a terrible thing to suggest.  First, it violates good normalization practices (there _are_ situations where this should be violated, but I doubt this is one of them).  Second, it's _terrible_ for maintenance (what happens if he adds another server?).  Third, it's also incredibly difficult to query sanely.

Comment: @ X-Zero I edited the answer to what i recommend.  I feel i should not get downvoted for answering the question in hand.  It is not good practice, but it was what he asked for

Comment: Given that he already _has_ two tables, with one of the tables being the score, modifying it won't really have a good effect.  You're not getting downvoted for being 'off topic' - you're being downvoted because I consider the answer 'unhelpful' or _potentially_ 'dangerous'.  The OP was specifically asking how to retrieve result rows in the given format, which does **not** require table modifications.

Comment: Now, if the question included notes about poor performance/long runtimes, and was noted as being solely for analysis purposes, then your suggestion has merit as a _new_ table(s) in an OLAP role (slowly changing dimensions).  However, it'd still likely be (initially) loaded and maintained similarly to some of the other answers.